# FPDF Reduce file size

Tags: php, pdf, pdf-generation, fpdf

I'm using FPDF to generate PDF from my website.

The PDF files generated are at least 2.2 Mb.

I read in another topic that it could be a consequence of the picture I introduce in my PDF, but in my case, there is not picture in my PDF.

How can I reduce the size of the PDF files generated by FPDF?

Comment: 1 - What does "There is not picture in my PDF." mean? There should be a picture and it is missing? Or there is no picture to add to the PDF so you think the file should be smaller? Or something else again? 2 - What is "2.2 Mo"? Are you trying to say 2.2 Mb (megabytes)? Or something else?

Comment: Inspect the PDF and check where all the bytes go. It may be something like a set of fonts that get completely embedded.

Comment: What's the size of the text in the PDF if you were to save it as a textfile?  (You won't get a lower size than that without compression.)